# What are the basic steps to make a printed circuit board?

Tags: shields, system-design

I created a shield for Arduino on a soldering board. The next step shall be to implement the circuit on a PCB. I'm new to this, so I'd like to know what the basic steps in designing a PCB are.

More specifically,

1. What software do I use for this? Is free software sufficient, or do I get substantially more value from a commercial package?
2. Can I have a single PCB printed by a commercial provider, or are there minimum quantities? What is the approximate cost for a shield-sized PCB in a small quantity - is it in the tens, or rather in the hundreds of bucks?

Of course, any pointers to good tutorials on the Web will be appreciated,  too!

Answer (score 2):

Software packages are, amongst others

- [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/) (more target at beginners)
- [Eagle](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/download-eagle/freeware/) (free for board of size 100 x 80 mm (4 x 3.2 inches)).
- [KiCad](http://www.kicad-pcb.org/display/KICAD/KiCad+EDA+Software+Suite) (open source)

Companies that make you pcb in small quantities are e.g.

- [OSHPark](https://oshpark.com/)
- [seeedstudio](https://www.seeedstudio.com/service/index.php?r=pcb)
- [Dirt Cheap Dirty Boards](http://dirtypcbs.com/)

I personally create my own double layer PCBs at home. I first started with the toner-transfer method, but now use photo lithography. I etch in Hydrochloric acid and hydrogen-peroxide. I can have a finished board in 1-2 hours, instead of having to wait a week or so. Great learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

> What software do I use for this? Is free software sufficient, or do I get substantially more value from a commercial package?

There are plenty of good free ones, or free versions of commercial ones. Use the one that best suits your way of working - they are all different, try some out and find out which you like best.  I use a free one for all my work (but then I am a FOSS junkie).

> Can I have a single PCB printed by a commercial provider, or are there minimum quantities? What is the approximate cost for a shield-sized PCB in a small quantity - is it in the tens, or rather in the hundreds of bucks?

Generally, no.  It'd be just too costly.  There are small quantity houses around though, and I often use iTead for my prototyping, since they will do batches of just 10 boards at a reasonable cost.

The basic steps in designing a PCB though are:

1. Design it as a schematic
2. Lay it out as a PCB design
3. Get a prototype made
4. Build it
5. Correct the mistakes
6. Go back to 3

If you only want one circuit and it is a pretty simple one you might want to give making the PCB yourself a go - it's quite rewarding and if nothing else gives you good insights into PCB design requirements and how best to lay out a PCB and the tracks for a good reliable etch.  If you have a laser printer the [Toner Transfer](http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/toner-transfer-etching-part-1-designing-the-circuit) method of home PCB production is good.

Comment: it seems that your toner transfer link above is broken.